# Angular application requred node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am going to create my first angular application. I have read lots of angular tutorial and many of them mentioned node.js.I am really got confused here. 
Do we really need to install node.js and other dependencies to run angular application ? 
Can't I just add respective angular libraries in my eclipse and create Angular application?
 What are advantages of using node.js? 
Also it is necessary to add all angular code is under App folder?

Regards,
Dip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is said on note.js website

> Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run across distributed devices.

So it depends if you want to have server logic (services) or not. If you are creating just the UI of the app you don't need note.js. Also Angular is NOT dependable on note.js